# How to delete rows where there is a number In Column "A"?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, numeric, delete-row

In Column "A" I am trying to delete rows that begin with a number. So for example, in the image that I have posted, I want my macro to delete rows # 3 & 11.

[image]

```
 Sub RemoveNumbersFromColumnA()
  Dim X As Long, R As Long, Data As Variant
  Data = Range("A3", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
  For R = 3 To UBound(Data)
    For X = 3 To Len(Data(R, 3))
      If Mid(Data(R, 3), X, 3) Like "[0-9]" Then

      Rows("3:" & cell.Row - 1).Delete
Next
      Range("A3").Resize(UBound(Data)) = Data
Else if
End Sub
```

Comment: For clarity, I assume that by "variables" and "cells" you mean you want to delete the value of the cell, correct? This probably sounds nit-picky, but I want to be certain since deleting e.g. a cell in Excel means removing the entire cell and replacing it with other cells, typically by shifting cells up in the column, or left in the row. Likewise, variables may specific identifiers within a cell's formula.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with something that works slowly is this one:

```
Sub RemoveNumbersFromColumnA()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets(1)

    For i = 10 To 1 Step -1
        If IsNumeric(Left(wks.Cells(i, "A"), 1)) Then
            Debug.Print wks.Cells(i, "A"); " deleting..."
            wks.Cells(i, "A").Delete
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

The idea is to loop backwards and to check whether the leftmost part of the cell content is numeric. If it is numeric, then print the info in the immediate window and delete it. This is what you get, pressing <kbd>F8</kbd>, e.g. step-by-step:

[image]

Then you may continue, as saving the rows to be deleted to a single range and only deleting this range once at the end. Like this one:

```
Sub RemoveNumbersFromColumnA()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim rowsToDelete As Range

    For i = 1 To 10
        Set myCell = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, "A")
        If IsNumeric(Left(myCell, 1)) Then
            Debug.Print myCell; " adding..."
            If rowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
                Set rowsToDelete = myCell.EntireRow
            Else
                Set rowsToDelete = Union(rowsToDelete, myCell.EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    If Not rowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
        rowsToDelete.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Vityata, I really appreciate the support.  The macro you provided was very beneficial.  I chose the second macro because it deletes the entire row, whereas the first macro does not. Thanks!!!!

Comment: @RickyDhaliwal - the second one is faster, and better but in order to delete the line from the line `wks.Cells(i, "A")` should be changed to `wks.Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete`. Anyway, please consider marking the answer as accepted, in order to remove it from the unaccepted queue. - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers