# Delete Empty rows in multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote the code below to delete empty rows in multiple sheets. It works fine for few sheets, but it takes quite some time and I had to run it few times to get the work done. Now I need to apply this to about 100 sheets. Can someone help me to modify this code for that.

```
Sub delete_empty_rows()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As String

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
  For x = 12 To 60
    y = Cells(x, 3).Value

    If y = "" Then
      ws.Rows(x).Delete
    End If
  Next x
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Deleting one row at a time is very slow, also you will skip every other line since they will shift up. Use a [union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union).

Answer (score 1):

The **bug** in the code is that it misses a worksheet reference in the line `y = Cells.(x, 3).Value`.

It should be `y = ws.Cells.(x, 3).Value`.

Without the `ws`, the check is done towards the `ActiveSheet` and the actions are taken towards the looped sheet.

---

There are many ways to do what you need, this is one of them, deleting rows with a number in column A, between range("A1:A10"). If you loop through all the worksheets, `For Each wks in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` the code will do what you need with some changes:

```
Sub RemoveNumbersFromColumnA()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim rowsToDelete As Range

    For i = 1 To 10
        Set myCell = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, "A")
        If IsNumeric(Left(myCell, 1)) Then
            Debug.Print myCell; " adding..."
            If rowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
                Set rowsToDelete = myCell.EntireRow
            Else
                Set rowsToDelete = Union(rowsToDelete, myCell.EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    If Not rowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
        rowsToDelete.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

From this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59637372/5448626

Comment: While this solves the question (+1) properly, it may be worth to mention that the *"bug"* is not **only** the missing sheet reference but also that deleting rows within a loop changes the row counting in a sheet and therefore makes the loop jumping a row after every row delete. Therefore looping backwards `For x = 60 To 12 Step -1` is necessary or collecting all rows with `Union` and delete after the loop (as you did). Just in case anyone is wondering why.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - yup, true.